# Unique fields that allow nulls in Django

Tags: django, orm, django-models

I have model Foo which has field bar. The bar field should be unique, but allow nulls in it, meaning I want to allow more than one record if bar field is `null`, but if it is not `null` the values must be unique.

Here is my model:

```
class Foo(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=40)
    bar = models.CharField(max_length=40, unique=True, blank=True, null=True, default=None)
```

And here is the corresponding SQL for the table:

```
CREATE TABLE appl_foo
(
    id serial NOT NULL,
     "name" character varying(40) NOT NULL,
    bar character varying(40),
    CONSTRAINT appl_foo_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id),
    CONSTRAINT appl_foo_bar_key UNIQUE (bar)
)
```

When using admin interface to create more than 1 foo objects where bar is null it gives me an error: "Foo with this Bar already exists."

However when I insert into database (PostgreSQL):

```
insert into appl_foo ("name", bar) values ('test1', null)
insert into appl_foo ("name", bar) values ('test2', null)
```

This works, just fine, it allows me to insert more than 1 record with bar being null, so the database allows me to do what I want, it's just something wrong with the Django model. Any ideas?

**EDIT**

The portability of the solution as far as DB is not an issue, we are happy with Postgres. 
I've tried setting unique to a callable, which was my function returning True/False for specific values of *bar*, it didn't give any errors, however seamed like it had no effect at all.

So far, I've removed the unique specifier from the *bar* property and handling the *bar* uniqueness in the application, however still looking for a more elegant solution. Any recommendations?

Comment: I can not comment yet so here a little addition to mightyhal: Since Django 1.4 you would need `def get_db_prep_value(self, value, connection, prepared=False)` as method call. Check https://groups.google.com/d/msg/django-users/Z_AXgg2GCqs/zKEsfu33OZMJ for more informations. Following method works for me, too: def get_prep_value(self, value): if value=="": #if Django tries to save '' string, send the db None (NULL) return None else: return value #otherwise, just pass the value

Comment: I opened a Django ticket for this. Add your support. https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/30210#ticket

Answer (score 191, accepted):

Django has not considered `NULL` to be equal to `NULL` for the purpose of uniqueness checks since ticket #9039 was fixed, see:

http://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/9039

The issue here is that the normalized "blank" value for a form `CharField` is an empty string, not `None`. So if you leave the field blank, you get an empty string, not `NULL`, stored in the DB. Empty strings are equal to empty strings for uniqueness checks, under both Django and database rules.

You can force the admin interface to store `NULL` for an empty string by providing your own customized model form for `Foo` with a `clean_bar` method that turns the empty string into `None`:

```py
class FooForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Foo

    def clean_bar(self):
        return self.cleaned_data['bar'] or None

class FooAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    form = FooForm
```

Comment: If bar is blank then replace it with None in pre_save method. Code will be more DRY I suppose.

Comment: This answer only helps for form-based data input, but does nothing to actually protect data integrity. Data may be entered via import scripts, from the shell, through an API or any other means. Much better to override the save() method than to make custom cases for every form that might touch the data.

Comment: Django 1.9+ requires a `fields` or `exclude` attribute in `ModelForm` instances. You can work around this by omitting the `Meta` inner class from the ModelForm for use in admin. Reference: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.form

Comment: This answer is suboptimal, you can see the answer from @tBuLi for why.

Answer (score 66):

** **edit 11/30/2015**: In python 3, the  module-global `__metaclass__` variable is [no longer supported](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14078755/django-custom-model-fields-to-python-not-called).
Additionaly, as of `Django 1.10` the `SubfieldBase` class was [deprecated](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/releases/1.8/#subfieldbase):

> #### from the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/releases/1.8/#subfieldbase):
>
> `django.db.models.fields.subclassing.SubfieldBase` has been deprecated and will be removed in Django 1.10.
>   Historically, it was used to handle fields where type conversion was needed when loading from the database,
>   but it was not used in `.values()` calls or in aggregates. It has been replaced with [`from_db_value()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.Field.from_db_value).
>   **Note that the new approach does not call the `to_python()` method** on assignment as was the case with `SubfieldBase`.

Therefore, as suggested by the `from_db_value()` [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.Field.from_db_value) and this [example](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/howto/custom-model-fields/#converting-values-to-python-objects), this solution must be changed to:

```
class CharNullField(models.CharField):

    """
    Subclass of the CharField that allows empty strings to be stored as NULL.
    """

    description = "CharField that stores NULL but returns ''."

    def from_db_value(self, value, expression, connection, contex):
        """
        Gets value right out of the db and changes it if its ``None``.
        """
        if value is None:
            return ''
        else:
            return value


    def to_python(self, value):
        """
        Gets value right out of the db or an instance, and changes it if its ``None``.
        """
        if isinstance(value, models.CharField):
            # If an instance, just return the instance.
            return value
        if value is None:
            # If db has NULL, convert it to ''.
            return ''

        # Otherwise, just return the value.
        return value

    def get_prep_value(self, value):
        """
        Catches value right before sending to db.
        """
        if value == '':
            # If Django tries to save an empty string, send the db None (NULL).
            return None
        else:
            # Otherwise, just pass the value.
            return value
```

---

I think a better way than overriding the cleaned_data in the admin would be to subclass the charfield - this way no matter what form accesses the field, it will "just work."  You can catch the `''` just before it is sent to the database, and catch the NULL just after it comes out of the database, and the rest of Django won't know/care.  A quick and dirty example:

```
from django.db import models


class CharNullField(models.CharField):  # subclass the CharField
    description = "CharField that stores NULL but returns ''"
    __metaclass__ = models.SubfieldBase  # this ensures to_python will be called

    def to_python(self, value):
        # this is the value right out of the db, or an instance
        # if an instance, just return the instance
        if isinstance(value, models.CharField):
            return value 
        if value is None:  # if the db has a NULL (None in Python)
            return ''      # convert it into an empty string
        else:
            return value   # otherwise, just return the value

    def get_prep_value(self, value):  # catches value right before sending to db
        if value == '':   
            # if Django tries to save an empty string, send the db None (NULL)
            return None
        else:
            # otherwise, just pass the value
            return value
```

For my project, I dumped this into an `extras.py` file that lives in the root of my site, then I can just `from mysite.extras import CharNullField` in my app's `models.py` file.  The field acts just like a CharField - just remember to set `blank=True, null=True` when declaring the field, or otherwise Django will throw a validation error (field required) or create a db column that doesn't accept NULL.

Comment: in get_prep_value, you should strip the value, in case the value has several spaces.

Comment: Updated answer here works well in 2016 with Django 1.10 and using EmailField.

Comment: If you are updating a `CharField` to be a `CharNullField`, you'll need to do it in three steps. First, add `null=True` to the field, and migrate that. Then, do a data migration to update any blank values so they are nulls. Finally, convert the field to CharNullField. If you convert the field before you do the data migration, your data migration won't do anything.

Comment: Note that in the updated solution, `from_db_value()` should not have that extra `contex` parameter. It should be `def from_db_value(self, value, expression, connection):`

Comment: The comment from @PhilGyford applies as of 2.0.

Answer (score 31):

You can add `UniqueConstraint` with condition of `nullable_field=null` and not to include this field in `fields` list.
If you need also constraint with `nullable_field` wich value is not `null`, you can add additional one.

Note: UniqueConstraint was added since django 2.2

```
class Foo(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=40)
    bar = models.CharField(max_length=40, unique=True, blank=True, null=True, default=None)
    
    class Meta:
        constraints = [
            # For bar == null only
            models.UniqueConstraint(fields=['name'], name='unique__name__when__bar__null',
                                    condition=Q(bar__isnull=True)),
            # For bar != null only
            models.UniqueConstraint(fields=['name', 'bar'], name='unique__name__when__bar__not_null')
        ]
```

Comment: That works! but i get an IntegrityError exception instead of the form validation error. How do you handle that? Catch it and raise ValidationError in create+update views?

Comment: God, why did I have to scroll all the way down just for this? Thanks for saving me.

Comment: If bar is null, you would like to let insert again same name. I think this prevent for doing that. i.e. you would like to be able to insert ("name", null) twice.

Answer (score 20):

Because I am new to stackoverflow I am not yet allowed to reply to answers, but I would like to point out that from a philosophical point of view, I can't agree with the most popular answer tot this question. (by Karen Tracey)

The OP requires his bar field to be unique if it has a value, and null otherwise. Then it must be that the model itself makes sure this is the case. It cannot be left to external code to check this, because that would mean it can be bypassed. (Or you can forget to check it if you write a new view in the future)

Therefore, to keep your code truly OOP, you must use an internal method of your Foo model. Modifying the save() method or the field are good options, but using a form to do this most certainly isn't.

Personally I prefer using the CharNullField suggested, for portability to models I might define in the future.

Answer (score 14):

The quick fix is to do :

```
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):

    if not self.bar:
        self.bar = None

    super(Foo, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: be aware that using `MyModel.objects.bulk_create()` would bypass this method.

Comment: Does this method gets called when we save from admin panel? I tried but it doesnt.

Comment: @Kishan django-admin panel will skip these hooks unfortunately

Comment: @e-satis your logic is sound so I implemented this, but the error is still a problem. Im getting told null is a duplicate.

Answer (score 11):

This is fixed now that https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/4136 is resolved. In Django 1.11+ you can use `models.CharField(unique=True, null=True, blank=True)` without having to manually convert blank values to `None`.

Comment: This worked for me on Django 3.1 with `CharField` but not with `TextField` - the constraint failed as an empty string was still being passed by admin form.

Comment: doesnt work for `EmailField` on django Django 3.1

Comment: @Aditya Just tried it with Django 3.1.5 and it works with `EmailField`.

Comment: What about foreign keys? For example 2 fields that are FK, but one is nullable. (In DB it is a multi-column unique index

Answer (score 5):

Another possible solution

```
class Foo(models.Model):
    value = models.CharField(max_length=255, unique=True)

class Bar(models.Model):
    foo = models.OneToOneField(Foo, null=True)
```

Comment: This is not a good solution since you`re creating an unnecessary relation.

Answer (score 2):

If you have a model MyModel and want my_field to be Null or unique, you can override model's save method:

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    my_field = models.TextField(unique=True, default=None, null=True, blank=True) 

    def save(self, **kwargs):
        self.my_field = self.my_field or None
        super().save(**kwargs)
```

This way, the field cannot be blank will only be non-blank or null. nulls do not contradict uniqueness

Answer (score 1):

I recently had the same requirement. Instead of subclassing different fields, I chose to override the save() metod on my model (named 'MyModel' below) as follows:

```
def save(self):
        """overriding save method so that we can save Null to database, instead of empty string (project requirement)"""
        # get a list of all model fields (i.e. self._meta.fields)...
        emptystringfields = [ field for field in self._meta.fields \
                # ...that are of type CharField or Textfield...
                if ((type(field) == django.db.models.fields.CharField) or (type(field) == django.db.models.fields.TextField)) \
                # ...and that contain the empty string
                and (getattr(self, field.name) == "") ]
        # set each of these fields to None (which tells Django to save Null)
        for field in emptystringfields:
            setattr(self, field.name, None)
        # call the super.save() method
        super(MyModel, self).save()
```

Answer (score 0):

For better or worse, Django considers `NULL` to be equivalent to `NULL` for purposes of uniqueness checks. There's really no way around it short of writing your own implementation of the uniqueness check which considers `NULL` to be unique no matter how many times it occurs in a table.

(and keep in mind that some DB solutions take the same view of `NULL`, so code relying on one DB's ideas about `NULL` may not be portable to others)

Comment: This is not the correct answer.  See [this answer for explanation](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1400046/39396).

Comment: Agreed this is not correct.  I just tested IntegerField(blank=True, null=True, unique=True) in Django 1.4 and it allows multiple rows with null values.