# How can I allow empty fields in my ModelForm while still using unique = True?

Tags: python, django, django-forms

Currently in `models.py` I have

```
class ModelName(models.Model):
    rowname = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank = True, unique=True)
```

This does wonders as far as making sure the same value isn't submitted to the database twice but is there a way that I can have unique not raise an error when the value that is a duplicate is an empty string? Does `unique` take an exception argument?

Answer (score 6):

Essentially, you need to follow the advice in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1400046/500584). While Django considers `''` equal to `''` for purposes of uniqueness, it doesn't consider `NULL` equal to `NULL`. So you need to store `NULL` values instead of empty strings.

1. Change the field to allow `NULL`, by adding `null = True` in your model:

   ```
   rowname = models.CharField(..., blank = True, null = True, unique = True)
   ```
2. Change empty strings to `None` in the form:

   ```
   class ModelNameForm(forms.ModelForm):
       class Meta:
           model = ModelName
       def clean_rowname(self):
           return self.cleaned_data['rowname'] or None

   class ModelNameAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
       form = ModelNameForm
   ```

Comment: This answer was exactly what I was looking around for. Thanks!