# how do exclude field of method clean form's

Tags: django, django-forms

i necessary remove one field of method clear of my form but he is already declared how required=False. but in the template it has the clean method error if i leave it empty

```
ship = UnicodeField(max_length=61, label=_('user'), required=False)
```

how do i do to field not show error?

Comment: add `blank=True`

Comment: TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'blank'

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10159587/how-can-i-allow-empty-fields-in-my-modelform-while-still-using-unique-true?lq=1

Comment: does not work, same mistake