# Is there any more elegant way to add a value sensitive unique together constraint in Django Model?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-database

Here is the problem:

I have a model like this:

```
class UserBook(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    book = models.ForeignKey(Book)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    class Meta:
        unique_together = ("user", "book")
```

Obviously, this model already has a unique together constraint for field **user** and **book**. And probably there will be some entries like this in the database:

```
    ------------------------------
    |user_id  book_id  is_active |
    |      1        1          0 |
    |      1        2          0 |
    |      1        3          1 |
    ------------------------------
```

And I have one more constraint to add, which is each user can have at most one entry that the value of **is_active** field is 1(True).

Currently I solve this problem by changing the model into this:

```
class UserBook(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    book = models.ForeignKey(Book)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    key = models.charFeild(max_length=255, unique=True)

    class Meta:
        unique_together = ("user", "book")

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if self.is_active:
            self.key = "%s_%s" %(self.user_id, self.is_active)
        else:
            self.key = "%s_%s_%s" %(self.user_id, self.is_active, self.book_id)
```

Add a field **key**, and customize the **save** method of this model.

But the **max_length** cannot be greater than 255 in this approach(which is no need to worry in my case, but sometimes the **key** field may be very long).

So, I would like to know if there is any more elegant approach to solve this kind of problem.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Redefine the `is_active` to be as follows:

```
# Equals user ID if active; otherwise null.
is_active = models.IntegerField(null = True, unique = True)
```

The user IDs will be unique in the column (satisfying your desired constraint) and the many null values in the column won't violate the constraint, as discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/454436/unique-fields-that-allow-nulls-in-django).

Comment: I initially used this but it meant that the `is_active` field can have 3 potential values: `None`, `True`, `False` and as such Django Admin would present the field as a drop down with 'Yes' / 'No' when editing the item as opposed to a tickbox (boolean). Using Anthony's method solved the problem and should be the accepted answer in 2022.

Comment: @Patrick Sounds plausible to me. My Django knowledge is outdated at this point.

Answer (score 8):

In [Django 2.2](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/releases/2.2/) (currently released as beta1) you will be able to use [UniqueConstraint](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/constraints/#uniqueconstraint) which in addition to the list of `fields` can be passed a `condition`

> A **Q** object that specifies the condition you want the constraint to enforce.
>
> For example, **UniqueConstraint(fields=['user'], condition=Q(status='DRAFT')** ensures that each user only has one draft.

Answer (score 7):

Based on Nour's answer, you can do this:

```
class Meta:
    constraints = [
        models.UniqueConstraint(
            fields=['user'],
            condition=Q(is_active=True),
            name='unique active user book per user'
        ),
    ]
```

Comment: Unfortunately i am getting a wierd error `could not create unique index 'unique user' as key(user, is_active)=(6,f) is duplicated.` I am setting is_active = True but then also it is checking inactive users.