# Adding multiple Django users with a blank email

Tags: python, django, postgresql

I have a Django app using a PostgreSQL db, where the user migration has an email field with `unique=True`. My `User` model has:

```
email = models.EmailField(_('email address'), unique=True, blank=True)
```

I want to be able to create multiple users with blank emails, but when the email is not blank it has to be unique. Currently, when I create two users with a blank email I get this error:

> duplicate key value violates unique constraint "accounts_user_email_b2644a56_uniq"

EDIT: I have added this to the `save` method in the `User` model:

```
if not self.email:
    self.email = None
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unique fields that allow nulls in Django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/454436/unique-fields-that-allow-nulls-in-django)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A unique constraint will allow multiple rows with value `null`, but it won't allow multiple rows with value empty string.

Therefore, you should set `null=True` on the field, and then set `email=None` instead of `email=""`.

Comment: Quick and great answer :)

Comment: I've added `if not self.email: self.email = None` to the model's `save` method, but still get the same result.

Comment: Ok I'm using django rest framework and I had to change the serializer, not the model.