# How to use two unique constraints in Django model?

Tags: django, model, constraints

I have a Django model for a player of a game

```
class Player(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    team = models.ForeignKey('Team', on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True)
    game = models.ForeignKey('Game', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    objects = GameManager()

    class Meta:
       unique_together = ('name', 'game',)
```

I have only one unique constraint, that the name and the game are unique together.

Now, I would like to extend our page by adding registered users. So, I would add this to the model.

```
        user = models.ForeignKey('auth.User', on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True)
```

So, an registered user can subscribe to a game by adding a name, team, game, and his/her user. However, the user should only be able to add his account once to an game, which would be a second unique constrain

```
       unique_together = ('user', 'game',)
```

Is it possible to give  in Django two unique constraints to the model? Or do I have to search in the table manually prior to saving the new entries? Or is there a better way?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, in fact by default `unique_together` is a collection of collections of fields that are unique together, so something like:

```
class Player(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    team = models.ForeignKey('Team', on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True)
    game = models.ForeignKey('Game', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    objects = GameManager()

    class Meta:
       unique_together = (('name', 'game',), ('user', 'game',))
```

Here we thus specify that every `name, game` pair is unique, and every `user, game` pair is unique. So it is impossible to create two `Player` objects for the same `user` and `game`, or for the same `game` and `name`.

It is only because a single `unique_together` constraint is quite common, that one can also pass a single collection of field names that should be unique together, as is written in the [documentation on `Options.unique_together` [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/options/#django.db.models.Options.unique_together):

> **Sets** of field names that, taken together, must be unique:
>
> ```
> unique_together = (("driver", "restaurant"),)
> ```
>
> This is a tuple of tuples that must be unique when considered
>   together. It's used in the Django admin and is enforced at the
>   database level (i.e., the appropriate `UNIQUE` statements are included
>   in the `CREATE TABLE` statement).
>
> **For convenience, `unique_together` can be a single tuple** when dealing with a single set of fields:
>
> ```
> unique_together = ("driver", "restaurant")
> ```

Comment: Thanks, for this answer. But with this solution I have an issue: I would like to make the linking to the user account optional. (the field can be blank) However, unique together ends into the fact that only one non-linked player can join.

Comment: @Cometchaser: normally unique together will allow `NULL` to have multiple values, so I don't see the issue. Note that `blank` is more relevant to *forms* than to the model itself. It is sufficient to say `null=True` to allow `NULL` values.

Comment: Check this JIC: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62774209/1312850

Answer (score 5):

You should use `models.UniqueConstraint` ([reference](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/options/#unique-together)).

As noted in the reference:

> UniqueConstraint provides more functionality than unique_together. unique_together may be deprecated in the future.

Do this:

```
class Meta:
    constraints = [
        models.UniqueConstraint(fields=['name', 'game'], name="unique_name_game"),
        models.UniqueConstraint(fields=['user', 'game'], name="unique_user_game"),
 ]
```

Comment: Hi! Could you maybe edit your answer to add an explanation of how/why this improves on the accepted answer that has already been there for a while?

Comment: You should give each UniqueConstraint a different name otherwise this example would fail, e.g. `unique_name_game` and `unique_user_game`.

Answer (score 0):

For example please refer to this :-

```
class Stores(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    lat = models.FloatField()
    lng = models.FloatField()
    merchant = models.ForeignKey(Profile, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="stores")

    def __str__(self):
        return "{}: {}".format(self.name, self.address)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = 'Stores'


class Items(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50, unique=False)
    price = models.IntegerField()
    description = models.TextField()
    stores = models.ForeignKey(Stores, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="items")

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = "Items"
        unique_together = ('name', 'stores',)
```

Comment: Is this meant to be an answer to this question or was this posted here mistakenly?