# Django/MySQL Unique Constraint how to treat NULLs as equal

Tags: python, mysql, django, model

I have a Django model which has a recursive field. A simplified version is below. The idea is roughly to have a tree data structure in sql. The problem which I have is that, apparently, [Django does not treat NULLs as equal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/454436/unique-fields-that-allow-nulls-in-django). The problem now is that, since every tree's root has a 'null pointer' by necessity, I can have two identical trees but Django will treat them as different because of the NULL value. How can I implement the UniqueConstraint below so that two 'Link' objects with NULL link values and equal node values will be treated as identical, and fail the UniqueConstraint test? Thank you.

```
class Link(models.Model):
    node = models.ForeignKey(Node, on_delete=models.CASCADE) 

    link = models.ForeignKey('self', on_delete = models.CASCADE, null=True)


    class Meta:

        constraints = [
                models.UniqueConstraint(['node', 'link'], name='pipe_unique')
                ]
```

**EDIT**
Of course ideally the constraint would be enforced by the db. But even if I can enforce it in application logic by hooking somewhere or using a custom constraint, that would be good enough.

Comment: This is a MySQL issue. MySQL does not treat NULL columns as equal in unique constraints

Comment: @IainShelvington see update

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may be able to do this with a [custom constraint](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/constraints/#django.db.models.UniqueConstraint.condition)

```
UniqueConstraint(fields=['node'], condition=Q(link__isnull=True), name='unique_root_node')
```

EDIT:

If you wished to manually add the check you could do it in the `save` method of `Link` and also in the `clean` method so that it get's run in any model forms before you even get to saving the instance

```
def clean(self):
    if self.node_id and not self.link_id:
        if self.__class__.objects.exclude(pk=self.pk).filter(node=self.node, link__isnull=True).exists():
            raise ValidationError(f'A root node already exists for {self.node}')
```

Excluding `pk=self.pk` avoids getting conflicts with itself when updating an object

```
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    self.clean()
    super().save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: This didn't work. I'm going through the Django codebase trying to see why.