# How to save model in Django with unique but null fields

Tags: django, model, unique-constraint

How can I save a model that should be unique but also allowed to be null in Django. For instance I have the following model...

```
class PetOwner(models.Model):
    """Model representing a pet owner."""

    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=50, help_text="Enter owner's first name")
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=50, help_text="Enter owner's last name")
    email = models.EmailField(
        max_length=50, blank=True, unique=True, help_text="Enter owner's email"
    )
    phone_number = models.CharField(
        max_length=15, blank=True, unique=True, help_text="Enter owner's phone number"
    )
    address = models.ForeignKey(
        "Address", on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, blank=True
    )
```

I want my app to work the following way. A `PetOwner` can sign up but when they do they initially only sign up with a `username`, `password`, a confirmation password, and `first_name`, and `last_name`. I want my to have a profile page which will allow for updating the `PetOwner` to include their `phone_number` but I do not necessarily want to make this a requirement. I decided that I'd make `phone_number` field `null=True` and `blank=True` but as soon as I register a second user I get a `django.db.utils.IntegrityError: UNIQUE constraint failed: app_petowner.phone_number` error. I believe it is because when I register a user for some reason instead of `phone_number` being `None` even when I did not actually add a phone number at all it shows up as an empty string. Not sure why this is happening and I am not sure how to fix it.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/454436/unique-fields-that-allow-nulls-in-django

Comment: Thanks SANGEETH SUBRAMONIAN, I tested it out and it worked. I lost connection last night right before I was able to send this message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that the problem is that you actually sending empty string, not null. You have to explicitly set phone number to None, before saving. Actually you can check if it is truth. Just make if phone_number == "": print something

Comment: Thanks, yeah I actually ended up doing what you mentioned based on SANGEETH SUBRAMONIAM's answer. I'll go ahead. Quick question though, It's weird that `default=None` woudn't work to achieve the desired outcome. Why is that?

Comment: @Thesilentone This is because you don't have phone_number field null property set to True and by the default it is False. You are looking for Field options in here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/db/models/#fields