# (1062, "Duplicate entry '' for key 'email'") and (1062, "Duplicate entry '' for key 'phone'") in Django

Tags: python-3.x, django, forms

I am trying to implement Sign Up page in Django using User models. In HTML page, there is an input field for email or phone number. The value I got from this field is assigned to `username` in Django User model and if the entered value is email, then the value is assigned to `email` in the User model. Otherwise value assigned to the `phone` in the User model. When I run the server, user can enter his details with email once. For the second time onwards, I got an error like this:

```
IntegrityError at /Accounts/CandidateRegister/
(1062, "Duplicate entry '' for key 'phone'")
Request Method: POST
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/Accounts/CandidateRegister/
Django Version: 4.0.2
Exception Type: IntegrityError
Exception Value:    
(1062, "Duplicate entry '' for key 'phone'")
Exception Location: C:\job\venv\lib\site-packages\MySQLdb\connections.py, line 254, in query
Python Executable:  C:\job\venv\Scripts\python.exe
Python Version: 3.9.7
Python Path:    
['C:\\job\\jobsite',
 'C:\\Users\\Student\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python39\\python39.zip',
 'C:\\Users\\Student\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python39\\DLLs',
 'C:\\Users\\Student\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python39\\lib',
 'C:\\Users\\Student\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python39',
 'C:\\job\\venv',
 'C:\\job\\venv\\lib\\site-packages']
```

Similarly, when a user enter with his phone number, their details will saved to database once. After that I got an error like this:

```
IntegrityError at /Accounts/CandidateRegister/
(1062, "Duplicate entry '' for key 'email'")
Request Method: POST
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/Accounts/CandidateRegister/
Django Version: 4.0.2
Exception Type: IntegrityError
Exception Value:    
(1062, "Duplicate entry '' for key 'email'")
Exception Location: C:\job\venv\lib\site-packages\MySQLdb\connections.py, line 254, in query
Python Executable:  C:\job\venv\Scripts\python.exe
Python Version: 3.9.7
Python Path:    
['C:\\job\\jobsite',
 'C:\\Users\\Student\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python39\\python39.zip',
 'C:\\Users\\Student\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python39\\DLLs',
 'C:\\Users\\Student\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python39\\lib',
 'C:\\Users\\Student\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python39',
 'C:\\job\\venv',
 'C:\\job\\venv\\lib\\site-packages']
```

Can anyone suggest a solution to solve this issue.

HTML code:

```
<form style="padding:10px 25%;" class="signup-form" id="candidate" method="POST" action="{% url 'candidateregister' %}">
                         {% csrf_token %}
                      <div class="form-row">
                        <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                          <label for="cafname" style="font: normal normal normal 16px/18px Poppins;">First name</label>
                          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="cafname" name="cafname" placeholder="Your first name" style="font-family:sans-serif;border:2px solid #d4d2d2;" required>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                          <label for="calname" style="font: normal normal normal 16px/18px Poppins;">Last name</label>
                          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="calname" name="calname" placeholder="Your last name" style="font-family:sans-serif;border:2px solid #d4d2d2;" required>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                      <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="caemorpn" style="font: normal normal normal 16px/18px Poppins;">Email or Phone number</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="caemorpn" name="caemorpn" placeholder="Enter email or phone number" style="font-family:sans-serif;border:2px solid #d4d2d2;" required>
                      </div>
                      <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="capassword1" style="font: normal normal normal 16px/18px Poppins;">Password</label>
                        <input type="password" class="form-control" id="capassword1" name="capassword1" placeholder="Enter your password" style="font-family:sans-serif;border:2px solid #d4d2d2;" required>
                      </div>
                      <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="capassword2" style="font: normal normal normal 16px/18px Poppins;">Confirm Password</label>
                        <input type="password" class="form-control" id="capassword2" name="capassword2" placeholder="Confirm your password" style="font-family:sans-serif;border:2px solid #d4d2d2;" required>
                      </div>
                      <div class="form-group">
                        <div class="form-check">
                          <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" id="cagridCheck" name="cagridCheck" style="font-family:sans-serif;border:2px solid #d4d2d2;" required>
                          <label class="form-check-label mt-3" for="cagridCheck" style="font: normal normal normal 15px/23px Poppins;color: #000000;">
                              I agree with the <a href="" style="color:#5A71E1;text-decoration:none;font: normal normal 600 15px/23px Poppins;">Terms and conditions</a>
                          </label>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                      <input type="hidden"  id="catype" name="catype" value="Candidate"/>
                        {% for msg in messages %}
                <center>
                    <h4 style="color:red;">{{msg}}</h4>
                </center>
                {% endfor %}
                      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block btype" style="background-color:#486DFC;margin-top:5%;font-family:sans-serif;">SIGN UP</button>
                    </form>
```

models.py

```
class User(AbstractUser):
email = models.CharField(max_length=30,unique=True)
phone = models.CharField(max_length=30,unique=True)
terms_and_conditions_confirmed = models.BooleanField()
otp = models.CharField(max_length=6)
type = models.CharField(max_length=30)
```

views.py

```
def candidateregister(request):
  User = get_user_model()
  if request.method=='POST':
      fname = request.POST.get('cafname')
      lname = request.POST.get('calname')
      email_phone = request.POST.get('caemorpn')
      password1 = request.POST.get('capassword1')
      password2 = request.POST.get('capassword2')
      terms = request.POST.get('cagridCheck')
      type = request.POST.get('catype')
      if terms == 'on':
          terms = True
      else:
          terms = False

      regex = r'\b[A-Za-z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z|a-z]{2,}\b'

      if (re.fullmatch(regex, email_phone)):
          if (User.objects.filter(email=email_phone).exists()):
              messages.info(request, "Email ID Already Taken")
              return redirect('register')
          user = User.objects.create_user(first_name=fname, last_name=lname, password=password1,
                                        terms_and_conditions_confirmed=terms, type=type, email=email_phone,username=email_phone)
        user.save()
          return redirect('login')
      else:
          if (User.objects.filter(phone=email_phone).exists()):
              messages.info(request, "Phone number Already Taken")
              return redirect('register')
          user = User.objects.create_user(first_name=fname, last_name=lname, password=password1,
                                        terms_and_conditions_confirmed=terms, type=type,phone=email_phone,username=email_phone)
          user.save()
          return redirect('login')
```

Comment: You don't assign to User.phone in your first branch.. so perhaps it is default value (""), while it is supposed to be unique? Have you checked your database?

Comment: Yes. When I enter email, phone field in the database table does not contain any value. Similarly When I enter phone, email field in the database table does not contain any value. What  modifications should I do in the code?@Jeppe

Comment: In `candidateregister`, you have two lines that start like this: `user = User.objects.create_user(...` - in the first,  you don't say `phone=email_phone` and in the second you dont say `email=email_phone`. Your model requires both of these to be unique. So maybe you need to set them as `null=True` (optional/nullable). I don't know if it can handle both `null` and `unique` - try it out.

Comment: First part works properly. In Second part , same error occurs. I gave `null=True` to both email and phone . That is '(1062, "Duplicate entry '' for key 'phone'")`@Jeppe

Comment: Can you try explicitly setting it `phone=None` and `email=None`? This sounds like it can be set to empty string rather than null: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/454436/unique-fields-that-allow-nulls-in-django) And maybe also update the records in your DB that now has empty string as values.

Comment: How should I explicitly set `phone=None` and `email=None`?@Jeppe

Comment: `User.objects.create_user(phone=None, first_name=fname, ...`

Comment: I got the same error when I explicitly set `phone=None` and `email=None`. When I removed `unique=True` from email field , it works without any error. The issue is, we cannot use `unique=True` and `null=True` together. Is there any other way to implement the email field `unique=True` at the same time make it as `null'@Jeppe

Answer (score 0):

Just set unique=False in models.py
example:

```
class User(AbstractUser):
   email = models.CharField(max_length=30,unique=False)
   phone = models.CharField(max_length=30,unique=False)
```